# Airflow - Parallel execution within a Task

Tags: python, celery, airflow

I have a DB table which looks like:

```
name        last_successful
dataset1    2020-11-07 10:30
dataset2    2020-11-07 10:30
```

Now I want to schedule a workflow in airflow which does the following:

1. Read all dataset `name` and `last_successful` from the DB.
2. For each dataset check for completion of data corresponding to the next 30 min bucket `last_successful + 30 min` (Assume this to be a black box)
3. Write a _SUCCESS file in s3 data partition corresponding to any completed buckets found in step2 and update `last_successful` in the database.

Since the datasets are independent of each other, step 2+3 can be parallelized for each dataset. How can I do this in Airflow? I do not want to create separate task for each dataset as the list of datasets will keep on increasing.

Comment: You said that you don't want to create separate tasks - is it because you don't want to manually add new tasks? It's possble to dynamically create tasks i.e. based on a YAML configuration file.

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't want to do it manually.

Comment: is the list of datasets in name constant or is it subject to many changes (additions/removed etc..)? also what is the trigger to start a new run timebase?event base?

Comment: @Elad Yes, it's subject to changes. I'm running the job hourly

Comment: If it's subject to many changes that might be an issue. Airflow can handle dynamic dag/tasks but not the kind that changes in every run. Consider that Airflow constantly scan the dag file which means that if it needs to read from DB to do that you will end up with bombarding the DB with open connections. If you are willing to read the datasets names from file (csv/json) and then look them up in the db this problem can be solved.

Comment: @Elad Instead of file can I use a `Variable` in Airflow? Is it possible to set/reset a variable remotely? REST APIs are not available for the same

Comment: No, for the same reason. Reading Variable outside of operator scope is bad practice. You will bombard the backend metastore of airflow. In the next airflow versions it will also print warning for such action: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11925

You must avoid reading from DBs (any DBs) out side of operators scopes. Thus I suggested to read from file. When adding new entry all you need is to add the entry to the file and if your DAG is dynamic it will create a flow for it automaticly.

Comment: @Elad Thanks for the insights. Since I need to do this remotely, I'll use an s3 file for doing this. Will use S3Hook for reading the same

Comment: Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: @nish posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion on the comments.

Creating a DAG which as part of its parsing read records from DB is a bad practice. Airflow constantly parse the file and will open a connection to the DB to get the latest records. This means heavy connection load over the DB.
For that reason Airflow will add a warning for users who try to use this approach (see [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11925)). While the warning is on Airflow metastore backend the same applies for any other DB.

You can handle your use case by listing the dataset names in a file. If you will create a DAG with dynamic tasks you can open a "branch" for any new entry in the file. Then you can compare the entry against your DB in a dedicated operator to make sure it's valid one.

The approach could be something similar to:

```
def get_file():
    with open('your_file') as f:
         lines = f.read().splitlines()
    return lines

file_list = get_file()
 with DAG(dag_id='my_dag',...
) as dag:
   start_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task')
   for dataset in file_list:
          my_op = MyOperator(task_id=dataset)
          start_op >> my_op
```

That way every time you will add new dataset to the file it will automatically add branch for it with `MyOperator`